# mysql query to create graph using graphviz

Tags: php, mysql, graph, graphviz

I need to dynamically create a graph, from a mysql query which results change according to the user.  I have worked with **graphviz** and found it works fine for me.  I have created graphs before, using a table structure that allows me to do the work.  But this time,  the table structure is different and I cannot find an easy way to query the table and generate the graph.  Graphviz requires nodes to be sentenced like couples,  say `A->B; B->C;`.  My actual issue is that the table has a different structure, each row instead of being `parent->son`,  contains the whole branch.  So if I query,  I get something like `A->B->C->D->E`.  The data is queried from a view which doesn't have ordinals or indexes due to the fact it contains aggregated values.  My question is how can I query data in the graphviz required form?  Is there a way to ordinate or index a view?.  Thanks

Comment: Didn't really understand the rest of your question, but just in case: Graphviz understands `A->B->C->D->E` actually quite well.